# Обновление страницы после сохранения в модальном окне

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core

Js-код функции модального окна.

```
     $(function () {
     var placeholderElement = $('#modal-placeholder');

    $('button[data-toggle="ajax-modal"]').click(function (event) {
        var url = $(this).data('url');
        $.get(url).done(function (data) {
            placeholderElement.html(data);
            placeholderElement.find('.modal').modal('show');
        });
    });

    placeholderElement.on('click', '[data-save="modal"]', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var form = $(this).parents('.modal').find('form');
        var actionUrl = form.attr('action');
        var dataToSend = form.serialize();

        $.post(actionUrl, dataToSend).done(function (data) {
            var newBody = $('.modal-body', data);
            placeholderElement.find('.modal-body').replaceWith(newBody);
            var isNotValid = newBody.find('[name="IsValid"]').val() === 'False';
            if (!isNotValid) {
                placeholderElement.find('.modal').modal('hide');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Код контроллера

```
   public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Name")] Country 
   country)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(country);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));

        }

        return View(country);
    }
```

Вопрос: почему при успешном сохранении у меня не перезагружается страница, или как сделать, чтобы данные динамически подгружались на вью?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При отправке ajax запроса страница и не будет перезагружаться. Тем более при отправке формы с `event.preventDefault();` Всё что вы отправляете на сервер будет приходить как входной параметр в `done()` без каких либо перезагрузок. 
Теперь по делу. Предположу что Вы вставляете новую страну в БД. Верните на клиент `return true` и :

```
...(function(done) {
     if (done) {
       location.reload();
     }
     ...
   });
```

перезагрузит страницу (можно задержку добавить). Ну либо делайте еще один запрос на получение данных после сохранения. Или после сохранения сразу возвращайте на клиент весь массив данных для вывода, который получает клиент при перезагрузке страницы и добавляйте через JQuery, в Вашем случае, в необходимые поля.